# What's the right name (tag) for the equivalent of WPF, when used in a Universal Windows App?

Tags: discussion, tags

[In a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443048/why-does-raising-propertychanged-events-from-a-timer-cause-an-comexception), I was castigated for using the term (and tag) "WPF" to mean UI code written with XAML, but in a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app.

That may be a fair criticism, but if it's not called WPF, what should I be calling it?

Comment: chue x's advice to use [tag:uwp] + [tag:xaml] seems perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

You know, I've always wondered why so many people seem to erroneously tag their WinRT/UWP questions with [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf).

WPF is a traditional desktop UI framework, like WinForms, except that it is XAML-based, like Silverlight. The only thing that WPF has in common with UWP apps is XAML (and even WinRT/UWP XAML is really a neutered version of what you get with WPF and Silverlight). Other than that, a WPF app is almost certainly not a UWP app.

> That may be a fair criticism, but if it's not called WPF, what should I be calling it?

UWP. Or, more generally, [windows-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps). I *think* UWP is just the new name for the Windows Runtime in Windows 8 and 8.1, except with a unified API and made to work with all device families supported by Windows 10.

Your answer to your question raises an excellent point, however. Perhaps the reason so many people are tagging their WinRT/UWP questions with [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) is due to the misconception that WPF and WinRT refer to the same technology, or are at least interoperable. I'm not sure if that makes a case for keeping the [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) tag, however. I can see a developer stating in their question that they have a background in WPF, but keeping the [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) tag doesn't sit well with me because it miscategorizes the question as a WPF question when really, it pertains to WinRT code.

Comment: The only way this Q+A could be useful to somebody else is when a WPF programmer reads it.  That does make the [wpf] tag appropriate.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Fair enough.

Comment: *neutered*... Yeah, but I wish we got `{x:Bind}` </rant>